# Check if key exists in an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, xcode4.5

I have an array like this :

```
(
{
   
    City = SanFransisco;
   
    Latitude = "28.602704";
    
   
},
{
    City = SanFransisco;
   
    Latitude = "28.49379";
   
   
},
```

)

How can I check if array contains key with the name City at 0 index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSEnumerator *e = [array objectEnumerator];
id object;
while (object = [e nextObject]) {
  if([object objectForKey:@"City"] !=nil)
    return TRUE;
}
```

if no iteration:

```
id object = [array objectAtIndex:0];
if([object objectForKey:@"City"] !=nil)
    return TRUE;
```

Comment: I got it by the way u said,but i dont want to repeat it again and again.I just want to check at firstindex..How can I do it?

Comment: How can I check at a particular index(object)?